# MS Access (Office 365 enterprise) SQL Query to modify a date field

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Edited to append the final working Query result to the bootom of the Original post**

I'm relatively inexperienced at using MS Access. I am trying to write a SQL query where an inherited table of data is read. The date and 24 hour clock time field (separate entries)are read from the source table. If the time is within date-1 at 0800 through date 0759, then I want to keep the current date. Once the dates are converted, then I wish to write to a new table that shows the PSA, the resultant date, and the number of strikes.

Here is the source table:

```
PSA_Ltg
PSA    Date     GMT    PDT     polarity   lat    lon
E5     6/28/2023           2130    P          42.33  -119.33
E5     6/28/2023        400    N          42.01  -119.15
E5     6/27/2023       1550    N          42.00  -118.15
E5     6/27/2023        745    P          42.00  -119.61
```

Here is my Query:

```
Strikes_08-08
SELECT PSA_Ltg.PSA, PSA_Ltg.Date, Switch(PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800,(PSA_Ltg.[Date]),PSA_Ltg.[PDT]>=800,PSA_Ltg.[Date]+1) AS NewDate, Count(PSA_Ltg.polarity) AS Strikes INTO [Strikes_08-08]
FROM PSA_Ltg
GROUP BY PSA_Ltg.PSA, PSA_Ltg.Date;
```

And what I would want the output table to be:

```
Strikes_08-08
PSA Date      Strikes
E5  6/27/2023   1
E5  6/28/2023   2
E5  6/29/2023   1
```

When I run the Query, I get the error

> Your query does not include the the specified expression
> 'Switch(PSA_ltg.[PDT]<0800,PSA_Ltg.[Date],PSA_Ltg.[PDT]>=800,PSA_Ltg.[Date]+1)'
> as part of an aggregate function.

If I remove the Switch statement, then the query runs, but then of course I lose the date reassignment capability. It gives the following output table instead:

```
Strikes_08-08
PSA Date      Strikes
E5  6/27/2023   2
E5  6/28/2023   1
E5  6/29/2023   1
```

**Here is the final working Query**

```
Strikes_08-08
SELECT PSA_Ltg.PSA, Switch(PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800,(PSA_Ltg.[Date]),PSA_Ltg.[PDT]>=800,PSA_Ltg.[Date]+1) AS NewDate, Count(PSA_Ltg.polarity) AS Strikes INTO [Strikes_08-08]
FROM PSA_Ltg
GROUP BY PSA_Ltg.PSA,  Switch(PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800,(PSA_Ltg.[Date]),PSA_Ltg.[PDT]>=800,PSA_Ltg.[Date]+1);
```

Comment: try to put MAX or MIN around the switch command

Comment: Please elaborate and/or provide an example. I'm not following how that would remove the error.

Comment: your query must be like `SELECT 
PSA_Ltg.PSA
, PSA_Ltg.[Date]
,MIN( 
      Switch(
          PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800
                 ,PSA_Ltg.[Date],

          PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800
                 ,DATEAdd("d",1,PSA_Ltg.[Date])
)
 ) 
AS NewDate
, Count(PSA_Ltg.polarity) AS Strikes 
FROM PSA_Ltg
GROUP BY PSA_Ltg.PSA
, PSA_Ltg.[Date];`but i can not reproduce your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `GROUP BY PSA_Ltg.PSA, PSA_Ltg.Date`, this instructs MsAccess to produce exactly one row for each combination of these two columns. But you also included an expression (NewDate) on your SELECT list. MsAccess doesn't know this would evaluate to the same value for each combination of those column values, so it can't guarantee that there would be just one row for each combination of those columns. So, the rule is to have that entire expression added to the `GROUP BY`, like so:

```
SELECT 
     PSA_Ltg.PSA
   , PSA_Ltg.Date
   , Switch(PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800, PSA_Ltg.[Date]
           ,PSA_Ltg.[PDT]>=800,PSA_Ltg.[Date]+1) AS NewDate
   , Count(PSA_Ltg.polarity) AS Strikes 
INTO [Strikes_08-08]
FROM PSA_Ltg
GROUP BY      PSA_Ltg.PSA
   , PSA_Ltg.Date
   , Switch( PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800  , PSA_Ltg.[Date]
           , PSA_Ltg.[PDT]>=800 ,PSA_Ltg[Date]+1);
```

You can also use MIN or MAX to aggregate this expression, then MsAccess can be sure that there would be only be one value for each combination of the GROUP BY columns (as @nbk suggested). I personally think it is confusing, because it is not your intention to aggregate.

Comment: Thanks for the strong nudge toward what I was looking for @tinazmu!

I am looking to aggregate the results, but the previous suggestion adding Max or MIN wasn't cutting it alone.

I ended up dropping the PSA_Ltg.Date from the initial SELECT statement and also the GROUP BY, I then added the Switch statement into the GROUP BY as you suggested. Those changes produced the desired table I initially indicated I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To get your wanted result, you ca do

```
SELECT 
PSA
,NewDate as [Date]
, Count(polarity) AS Strikes 
FROM (
SELECT 
        PSA_Ltg.PSA
        , PSA_Ltg.[Date]
,PDT
,PSA_Ltg.polarity, 
      Switch(
          PSA_Ltg.[PDT]<800
                 ,PSA_Ltg.[Date],

          PSA_Ltg.[PDT]>=800
                 ,PSA_Ltg.[Date]+1
            )
 
AS NewDate

FROM PSA_Ltg)
 as A1
GROUP BY PSA
,NewDate;
```

The result is

[image]